# WordPress XML-RPC returns Internal Server Error

Tags: java, wordpress, xml-rpc

I send the following XML-RPC fragment to **update a page** (not a post) to a WordPress:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<methodCall>
  <methodName>wp.editPost</methodName>
  <params>
    <param>
      <value>
        <i4>0</i4>
      </value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <value>user</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <value>pass</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <value>
        <i4>30</i4>
      </value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <value>
        <struct>
          <member>
            <name>post_content</name>
            <value>xyz</value>
          </member>
          <member>
            <name>post_date</name>
            <value>Wed Jun 15 15:15:27 EDT 2016</value>
          </member>
          <member>
            <name>post_status</name>
            <value>publish</value>
          </member>
          <member>
            <name>post_title</name>
            <value>xxx Wed Jun 15 15:15:27 EDT 2016</value>
          </member>
          <member>
            <name>post_type</name>
            <value>page</value>
          </member>
          <member>
            <name>comment_status</name>
            <value>open</value>
          </member>
          <member>
            <name>ping_status</name>
            <value>open</value>
          </member>
        </struct>
      </value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodCall>
```

I manage to create a page, but not update it.

The server returns:
HTTP server returned unexpected status: Internal Server Error

Here is my Java stack, although I am pretty sure, Java is not the reason...

```
16-06-15 15:15:28:232 ERROR io.oplo.publish.components.Site - An exception was raised while talking to the website: HTTP server returned unexpected status: Internal Server Error
org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransportException: HTTP server returned unexpected status: Internal Server Error
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.getInputStream(XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.java:94)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:152)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcHttpTransport.java:143)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.java:69)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:56)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:167)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:158)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:147)
    at io.oplo.publish.components.Site.updateOrInsertPage0(Site.java:109)
```

And page with id #30 does exist...

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the issue, it seems that one, two, or the 3 of the 3 XML_RPC commands fail in an update:

- post_date
- comment_status
- ping_status